# How to have access to AppDelegate method handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession when creating a framework

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a framework and using AWS to upload data in the background.

I need to have code in the method that gets called in the projects AppDelegate,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    AWSS3TransferUtility.interceptApplication(application, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession: identifier, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

My current solution is to just call my framework when this gets called in the AppDelegate, but I do not want the users to have to include any code other than the code that starts the framework running. Is there anyways to have my line of code called with all the parameters from my framework without the person needing to call a method in my framework?

Answer (score 1):

After some thought I don't think there is a way to do this.

As far as I know there are two different ways to implement what you looking for, the one you are currently using, or create your own class of the AppDelegate that inherits `UIApplicationDelegate`

1.- Call your method from the App delegate, as you are doing, the cons of this approach as you are well aware are that you depend on Developers to Implement the method, and know where to implement it in the App Delegate.

---

2.- Create a Base AppDelegate class, You would need to tell the developers to Inherit their app delegate from your class.

```
class CustomAppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        AWSS3TransferUtility.interceptApplication(application, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession: identifier, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Their AppDelegate would inherit from it:

```
class AppDelegate: CustomAppDelegate{

}
```

The problem is that developers might not always follow this guideline, and even if they do, if they need to override that function, they would need to call the super method call in order for it to work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I agree that I couldn't think of anything better either. Whats really interesting is there is a framework similar to mine that uploads data in the background. The only thing I do is call the framework like framework.start() and everything works. Its driving me crazy wondering how they are uploading data in the background without access to my appdelegate.

Comment: Do you know the framework name? I can look into that if you want!